# Angular find where is the error come from undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have error in my program suddenly and i dont find where it comes from and the console show me this error from angular source, How i can know where in my code the error comes from?

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost/lottery-hunter/public/build/app.min.js:10:4161
    at Object.fn (http://localhost/lottery-hunter/public/build/app.min.js:8:21940)
    at h.$digest (http://localhost/lottery-hunter/public/build/app.min.js:8:22542)
    at h.$apply (http://localhost/lottery-hunter/public/build/app.min.js:8:24028)
    at f (http://localhost/lottery-hunter/public/build/app.min.js:8:4773)
    at F (http://localhost/lottery-hunter/public/build/app.min.js:8:6975)
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (http://localhost/lottery-hunter/public/build/app.min.js:8:7535)
```

Comment: Something related to an AJAX call, check success and error callbacks...

Comment: Use breakpoints in browser's console for debugging, step by step.

Comment: Use the developer tools to debug. If you can try to use the non minified version of the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is showed In your error message.You called some function,which is not a function.In your ..build/app.min.js there are some errors.there are the lines numbers. for example the first problem is in 10-th line